# docker container is not running (centos)

Tags: docker

I tried to start a container output as follows,

1. I have listed all available containers using docker ps --all.

> [root@sdctlt0048 express_edition]# docker    ps  --all
> CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                              COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                   PORTS                                            NAMES
> ceb4b5256c32   store/saplabs/hanaexpress:2.00.045.00.20200121.1   "/run_hana --passwor…"   6 hours ago   Exited (1) 3 hours ago                                                    express_edition
> 7d838bf619df   389fef711851                                       "echo hello"             4 days ago    Exited (0) 4 days ago                                                     helloWorld
> b743cad7815f   portainer/portainer-ce                             "/portainer"             2 weeks ago   Up 2 weeks               0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   portainer
> 47cc21a338dd   portainer/portainer                                "/portainer"             2 weeks ago   Exited (1) 2 weeks ago                                                    youthful_maxwell
> 97e277d42155   hello-world                                        "/hello"                 2 weeks ago   Exited (0) 2 weeks ago                                                    confident_roentgen

2. I entered the following commands to start the container which is in the exit stage and enter the terminal of this image.
   docker start ceb4b5256c32
   docker exec -it ceb4b5256c32 bach
3. It throws the following error.
   **FATA [0000] Error response from daemon: Container ceb4b5256c32 is not running**

But when I start the container using docker start ceb4b5256c32. It throws the container ID out, which is okay if everything is working normally. I am not sure what caused this error.
for my **docker run** i was created a script where I put all my commands as follows:

Any idea on the causes and suggestions on this would be very helpful to me.
many Thank in advance.

Comment: How did you originally `docker run` the container?  Can you edit the question to also include the image's Dockerfile, and any other source code required to reproduce the problem?  In normal use you shouldn't need `docker start`, and I'd reserve `docker exec` for debugging use.

Comment: je vous remercie pour votre réponse. j'ai crée un script ou j'ai met toute mes commandes comme suivant:

Comment: sudo docker run -p 39013:39013 -p 39017:39017 -p 39041-39045:39041-39045 -p 1128-1129:1128-1129 -p 59013-59014:59013-59014 -v /data/express_edition:/hana/mounts \
-d \
--ulimit nofile=1048576:1048576 \
--sysctl kernel.shmmax=1073741824 \
--sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range='40000 60999' \
--sysctl kernel.shmmni=4096 \
--sysctl kernel.shmall=8388608 \
--name express_edition \
store/saplabs/hanaexpress:2.00.045.00.20200121.1 \
--passwords-url file:///hana/mounts/password.json \
--agree-to-sap-license

Comment: Please edit the question and include these details there, with proper code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Mb the container has already stopped when you want to execute the command?
Check if conatainer have a status Exited and logs

```
docker ps | grep ceb4b5256c32
docker logs ceb4b5256c32 --tail 5
```

If the container always stops and this is normal then try it (--rm - remove container after stopped):

```
docker run --rm -it <image:name> <command>
```

Eg:

```
# ~ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

# ~ docker run --rm -it debian bash
root@22ce8b31b68c:/# exit
exit

# ~ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

# ~
```